# Миграция драйвера из установщика в OC Windows

Tags: windows, драйвер, samba, pxe

В кратце суть вопроса, возможно ли мигрировать/извлечь определившийся-текущий драйвер из среды WindowsPE в устанавливаемую систему?

Имеется ПК с настроенной связкой TFTP-сервер и SAMBA-сервер, для установки ОС по сети. Для установки используется `boot.wim` извлеченный из офф. образа Windows 10, с его помощью вызывается среда WindowsPE и соответсвенно `setup.exe` из подмонтированной шары. Очевидно в `boot.wim` имеется определенный набор сетевых драйверов для данных манипуляций. Была мысль извлечь `.inf` файлы и использовать `SetupComplete.cmd` но т.к. установки производятся на разное железо, крайне не хотелось бы тянуть весь комплект и создавать конфликты. Реально ли вытянуть и использовать текущий используемый драйвер WindowsPE или может есть ещё какие альтернативы?

**P.S. Хотелось бы избежать ручной установки сетевых драйверов с других устройств, т.к. цель сей задумки, избавиться от вороха установочных флешек.**

Comment: Ну а остальные дрова ты как собираешься подсовывать?

Comment: Для остальных драйверов есть офф. сайт конкретных железяк.

Comment: Ну а на сетевухи не выкладывают что ли?